# How to use a Module in a Class

Tags: vb.net, class, module

As it says [on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7825002w%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> Both classes and modules are reference types that encapsulate the items defined within, but they differ in how items are accessed from other procedures.

How is it possible to use a Module inside a Class? How would I access its members and use them?

***EDIT #1***
I tried to access this module in all possible ways,

`Dim memman as MemoryModule`

but it gives me an error, *Module 'MemoryModule' cannot be used as a type.*

Comment: I imagine you'd access it like any other `Shared` code.  Did you try?  In what way did your attempt not succeed?

Comment: A quick **Google** search yielded me over `635,000` possible solutions, just a thought. Anyway's here's one link to check out: http://www.dotnetperls.com/class-vbnet

Comment: @AxDSanMuramasa also please **do not** post your code in the comment's section, it become's a mess; update your question above with what you have tried and where you are having issues.

Comment: you can invoke ("call") methods in the module from a class *instance* (or just make them shared methods in the class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment on the question...

> Dim memman as MemoryModule

This is incorrect.  Modules aren't classes, they can't be instantiated as objects.  You can essentially think of a module as being a collection of `Shared` helper functions.  And you'd access those like any other `Shared` function:

```
MemoryModule.SomeFunction()
```

So, for example, if your module looks like this:

```
Module MemoryModule
    Sub PerformAnOperation()
        ' some function logic
    End Sub
End Module
```

Then any class which can see that module can invoke that function:

```
MemoryModule.PerformAnOperation()
```

---

If logically your "memory module" *should* be an object capable of separate instances, then it shouldn't be a `Module`.  Instead, you'd want to make it a `Class` and implement it with instance members instead of `Shared` members.  It's important to structure your code according to the logic and concepts it represents.

Comment: This worked, but inside a Function, is it meant to behave like that?

Comment: PerformAnOperation doesn't need to be scoped in (and they are defaulted to `Public`), which is important because you might have the same variable name elsewhere in your Class.

Comment: @AxDSanMuramasa: Modules are meant to behave like `Shared` members, yes.  Whether or not *your application logic* is meant to behave like that... we can't know.  Is there some logical error you're facing or something which doesn't make sense in the code?

Comment: @David, then no, if that's how it should be then, I was doing the wrong invocation to the Module and probably calling it outside a scope, so far as you have showed already it worked.